Alt + Tab old mode
After an update a few days ago the old mode with ALT + TAB is no longer working
This is how I used to enable the classic mode (which doesn't work anymore)
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

; Old style ALT+TAB
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer]
"AltTabSettings"=dword:1
; Reset: Delete key "AltTabSettings"

After the lastest update the entry in the regedit was deleted. I tried to create the entry again, but after that the dialog with the open tabs no longer works. You just tab directly between each window
